# Conversion of an infix operation to a postfix operation

Tags: java, postfix-notation

The code takes in an infix operation and converts it to a postfix operation. I have been able to to the conversion. The problem I'm facing is the spacing between operators. Also, I'd like to know how the postfix operation can be evaluated.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class InToPost {
   private Stack theStack;
   private String input;
   private String output = "";
   public InToPost(String in) {
      input = in;
      int stackSize = input.length();
      theStack = new Stack(stackSize);
   }
   public String doTrans() {
      for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
         char ch = input.charAt(j);
         switch (ch) {
         case '+': 
         case '-':
            gotOper(ch, 1); 
            break; 
         case '*': 
         case '/':
         case '%':
            gotOper(ch, 2); 
            break; 
         case '(': 
            theStack.push(ch);
            break;
         case ')': 
            gotParen(ch); 
            break;
         default: 
            output = output + ch; 
            break;
         }
      }
      while (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
         output = output + theStack.pop();
      }
      System.out.println(output);
      return output; 
   }
   public void gotOper(char opThis, int prec1) {
      while (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
         char opTop = theStack.pop();
         if (opTop == '(') {
            theStack.push(opTop);
            break;
         }
         else {
            int prec2;
            if (opTop == '+' || opTop == '-')
               prec2 = 1;
            else
               prec2 = 2;
            if (prec2 < prec1) { 
               theStack.push(opTop);
               break;
            }
            else
            output = output + opTop;
         }
      }
      theStack.push(opThis);
   }
   public void gotParen(char ch){ 
      while (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
         char chx = theStack.pop();
         if (chx == '(') 
            break; 
         else
            output = output + chx; 
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   throws IOException {
      String input = "13 + 23 - 42 * 2";
      String output;
      InToPost theTrans = new InToPost(input);
      output = theTrans.doTrans(); 
      System.out.println("Postfix is " + output + '\n');
   }
   class Stack {
      private int maxSize;
      private char[] stackArray;
      private int top;
      public Stack(int max) {
         maxSize = max;
         stackArray = new char[maxSize];
         top = -1;
      }
      public void push(char j) {
         stackArray[++top] = j;
      }
      public char pop() {
         return stackArray[top--];
      }
      public char peek() {
         return stackArray[top];
      }
      public boolean isEmpty() {
         return (top == -1);
     }
   }
}
```

The postfix output for this is:

```
13  23 + 42  2*-
```

whereas I am trying to get an output that looks like this:

```
13 23 + 42 2 * -
```

I am unable to space the operator in the output.

Comment: You are absorbing all the spaces in the input as part of the operands. This is not correct and will cause further failures when you come to evaluate the postfix. You need to ignore spaces in the input and provide it in the output around the operators, or whatever you require. Evaluating the postfix is trivial once you have it.